# Why do we need regularization for linear least sqaures given that a line is the simplest model possible?

Tags: linear-regression, regularized

In linear least squares  we are trying to fit a line to data. A line is the simplest model that can be fit to the data. How is it possible for a linear model to over-fit the data? In short why do we need regularization for fitting a line to a data?

Comment: The concern is with overfitting to the *training* data and the model not being able to generalize well to *new* data. As currently worded, your question is actually better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).  See [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).